# What is the suggested way to save and restore a technology agnostic database backup using Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-backups

We built a Java tool that uses Hibernate / JPA to persist and map data on SQL databases. We also provide an installer to ease the setup process. This installer is a Java program that is among others responsible for updating the database scheme to the new version.

We'd like to extend the functionality to generate and restore backups if necessary.

Is there a database technology-agnostic approach to this using JDBC? Is there an alternative to invoking database-specific scripts (for example pq_dump or mysqldump) as subprocess from within Java?

Comment: JDBC itself does not offer a database-agnostic backup API, and in its current form, your question is asking multiple questions, and - a bit reading between the lines - asking for tool recommendations. This makes your question off-topic.

Comment: JDBC Connection.getMetaData() allows a general querying of the database structure. But then you'll need to program.